# How to make a validate_data field optional?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I am trying to create a RESTful api endpoint for creating a new user. And this is what I put in my serializer.py

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    Class Meta:
        model = User
        field = ('name', 'division', 'image',)
        extra_kwargs = {'division': {'required': False}}

    def create(self, validated_data):
        newUser = User.objects.create(
           name = validated_data['name'],
           division = validated_data['division']
           image = validated_data['image']
        )
        return newUser;
```

Now what I want to do is I want to make the division optional, for example, if the input division is "Education" then put is as education is my database table; But make it empty if there's no input. How can realize this?

Comment: If the field is optional in your model definition (i.e. has `null=True` and `blank=True`) you don't have to do anything in your serializer. Can you post the code for your `User` model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    division = None
    if validated_data['division']:
        division = validated_data['division']
    newUser = User.objects.create(
        name = validated_data['name'],
        division = division
        image = validated_data['image']
    )
    return newUser;
```

Comment: Yes. I did figured this out. But what if I have more than 10 different fields that might be empty than I have to create the if statement for each of those fields?

Answer (score 1):

To make a field optional, you can use the `extra_kwargs` dict. In order for this to work, the field must be explicitly declared in `fields`.

```
class FooSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ...

    class Meta:
        ...
        fields = ('bar', 'baz',)
        extra_kwargs = {'bar': {'required': False}}
```

In general, try not to use `fields = '__all__'` and instead explicitly declare fields. This will protect you from later accidentally exposing a sensitive field.

Comment: I actually added this under the fields but it doesn't work. I have updated my code

Comment: In order to use `extra_kwargs`, you must explicitly specify fields like `fields = ('name', 'division', 'image',)`.

Comment: It doesn't work even I specify the field. It will still ask for the field when I sent out the POST request.

Answer (score 0):

Using `null=True` and `blank=True` on the fields in the model definition, made those fields optional.

The answer is based on @slider 's comment under the question,